# Spring boot return all records if no page information passed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an API which is something like this

```
https://[HOSTNAME]/products?page=0&size=20
```

It returns 20 records. If I remove this information

```
https://[HOSTNAME]/products
```

then by default it returns only 10 records.

Backend API implementation is

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getProducts(
      @PathVariable (name="objectId") UUID categoryId,
      // ..other parameters
      @PageableDefault(page = 0) Pageable page) {

}
```

I am using Pageable for fetching data from database

```
productRepository
    .findByproductInAndStateIn(productIds, states, pageable);
```

What I am looking for is when I hit this url, then it should return all records

```
https://[HOSTNAME]/products
```

I tried to find the way but couldn't find any solution. Is there any way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

@PageableDefault has the following implementation

```
public @interface PageableDefault {

    int value() default 10;
    int size() default 10;
    int page() default 0;
    String[] sort() default {};
    Direction direction() default Direction.ASC;
}
```

So if you don't specify size, you are getting 10 records.

Either remove @PageableDefault annotation and specify the following property in your .yml file
`spring.data.rest.default-page-size = 99999999`

Or pass size value in @PageableDefault like this

`@PageableDefault(size = Integer.MAX_VALUE, page = 0)`